# Pdblp dataframe multiple securities

Tags: python, bloomberg

I am using below code for historical data via bbg api, question around df how should i define this df for multiple securities? it works fine for one security as below

thanks

```
import pdblp
con = pdblp.BCon()
con.start()
con.bdh(['IBM US Equity', 'MSFT US Equity'], ['PX_LAST'],
    '20061227', '20061231', elms=[("periodicityAdjustment", "ACTUAL")])

df = con.bdh('IBM US Equity','PX_LAST','20061227', '20061231')
```

Comment: basically df = con.bdh(['IBM US Equity', 'MSFT US Equity'], ['PX_LAST'],
    '20061227', '20061231', elms=[("periodicityAdjustment", "ACTUAL")]) and it will work for multiple securities ..

Comment: any good link to schedule this script in python to run at specific point in time?

Answer (score 0):

if we equate df as below and it will work for multiple securities,
next is to replace "LAST_PX" with adjusted price field,

```
  df = con.bdh(['IBM US Equity', 'MSFT US Equity'], ['PX_LAST'],
 '20061227', '20061231', elms=[("periodicityAdjustment", "ACTUAL")])
```